# Raycast doesn't detect hitting object unity C# 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

Quite new to Unity and I've been playing around with Raycasting the past few days. I have run into this problem where  the line that the raycast is meant to represent is not detecting that this has happened. So when the Raycast line hit the object I want it to simply display HIT onto the console to show that this is working. I have a feeling that the reason it isn't working is due to the fact that the line I'm seeing through debug and the line that is actually being used different.

The code is:

```
void rayCast()
    {
        if (player.transform.position.x <= enemy.transform.position.x)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hitLeft = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -transform.right, rayDistance, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
            Vector3 left = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.left);
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, left * rayDistance, Color.green);

            if (hitLeft.collider != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player is within range");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("out of range");
            }
        }


        if (player.transform.position.x >= enemy.transform.position.x)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hitRight = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, rayDistance, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
            Vector3 right = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right);
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, right * rayDistance, Color.green);

            if (hitRight.collider != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player is within range");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("out of range");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.right, rayDistance, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"));
```

It looks like you always raycast to the right. You probably want it to switch left and right, like you do when you're drawing your line.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have updated the code to switch it left and right but still had no luck.

Comment: I see that you've defined a custom collision layer `LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player")` I would make sure that its defined. If it is, try taking away the mask and having the raycast print out what it hit to determine where its going.

Comment: I made sure the layer was defined, however, the issue was that it was always colliding with the enemy(the sprite the rayCast was coming from) didn't think to check what it was colliding with, it's been fixed now. Thank you very much for you help, much appreciated.